# displaying -0.00% instead of 0.00 on the Y-axis

Tags: highcharts

I would like to display a very small negative value (like -0.00005%) as -0.00% instead of 0.00% (see printscreen).

Right now I got this code

````
    yAxis: [{
    labels: {
            style: {
                fontSize: '15.5px'
            }
        },
                tickInterval: 50
    }],
    xAxis: [{
        labels: {
            style: {
                fontSize: '15.5px'
            }
        }
    }],
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            dataLabels: {
                style: {
                    fontSize: '15.5px'
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
[example of very small negative value displayed as 0.00% instead of -0.00%][1]```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YXkq.png

Any idea how to solve this ?
thanks in advance
````

Comment: Hi @Phiphi, Could you add more details about your chart configuration? I've created a simple live example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4qn93soh/ with your code. Could you adapt the example to show the problem?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the example you provided. I tried successfully to use the tag format: '{y:.2f} %' in the datalabels section and it worked as I'm expected it (I saved it in your example). So I understand that my problem is lying with the data provided to the chart.  It is rounded wrongly and I cannot override this myself through the format tag. So I'm asking help of the data provider to solve this issue

Comment: I would be able to investigate more if you create a full working example with mocked data similar to the one you are receiving.